# Fast counting of interactions between groups given users interactions and groups assignments

Tags: python, matrix, cython, vectorization

Given:

- An array **c** that contains the group assignment of every user (`c[i]=4` indicates that user `i` belongs to group 4)
- A matrix **y** of 0 and 1 that indicates whether user `i` interacted with user `j` (`y[i][j] = 1` if `i` interacted with `j`, 0 otherwise)

What is the fastest way to count the number of interactions and lack of interactions between every pair of groups?

This is what I have:

**Solution 1**:

This is what I have:

```
import numpy as np

def test1(y, c):

    N = len(c) # number of users
    C = len(set(c)) # number of clusters 

    # Final counts matrices
    I = np.zeros((C,C)) 
    notI = np.zeros((C,C))

    # Loop every row i/ column j, look at the groups where the users belong
    # and update I accordingly
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            if y[i][j] == 1:
                I[c[i]][c[j]] += 1
            else: 
                notI[c[i]][c[j]] += 1

    return I, notI
```

*timeit*:

```
nusers = 100
nclusters = 4
y = np.random.random_integers(0, 1, (nusers,nusers))
c = np.random.choice(nclusters, nusers)

%timeit test1(y,c)
```

10 loops, best of 3: 42 ms per loop

**Solution 2:**

```
def test2(y, c):

    N = len(c)
    C = len(set(c))
    I = np.zeros((C,C))
    notI = np.zeros((C,C))

    for i, jj in enumerate(y):
        for j, value in enumerate(jj):
            if value:
                I[c[i]][c[j]] += 1
            else: 
                notI[c[i]][c[j]] += 1

    return I, notI
```

*timeit:*
10 loops, best of 3: 30.8 ms per loop

Comment: in Solution 2 you wrote `len(z)`, that is, "z" instead of "c". Typo? `z` is not defined in the posted code.

Comment: also, will it make a difference if you change `if y[i][j] == 1:` to `if y[i][j]:` ?

Comment: @janos it is a typo, thanks! And no, it would make no difference (actually I tested after posting the question and `y[i][j]:` seems a bit faster)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-formulating the problem into a matrix multiplication one speeds up the algorithm very much.

**Algebra:**

Create a matrix `G` of `n_groups` x `n_users` such that every column is a group mask, that is, all users (columns) that belong to that group (row) are flagged are 1 and 0 otherwise. If `Y` is the matrix of interactions, then the interactions between every pair of groups can be obtained by the following equation:

$$I = GYG^T$$

**Code:**

The code is:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import dot

def test3(y, c):

    N = len(c)
    C = len(set(c))
    noty = np.mod(y+1,2)

    # create C group masks of 1 (if user is belongs to group) and 0. 
    G = np.zeros((C,N))
    for group in range(C):
        G[group] = [1 if c_== group else 0 for c_ in c]

    # Groups (src) * interaction_matrix * Groups_transposed (dst)
    # Every row of Groups matrix is the mask of a group
    return dot(dot(G,y),G.T), dot(dot(G,noty),G.T)
```

1000 loops, best of 3: 810 µs per loop